# JavaScript Callback/this confusion with require.js / objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, requirejs

I try to use the following structure in my app: https://gist.github.com/jonnyreeves/2474026

I try to register some callback inside my constructor. I made an example using jquery, actually it's leaflet maps, but the difference shouldn't matter.

```
function Person() {
    this.name = "abc";

    $("#something").onSomeEvent(function() {
        this.name = "cde";
    });
}
```

How do I properly reference my object-property name, inside the callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
function Person() {
    this.name = "abc";
    $("#something").onSomeEvent(function() {
        this.name = "cde";
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   function Person() {
        var self = this;
        self.name = "abc";
        $("#something").onSomeEvent(function() {
            //this is right if you need
            self.name = "cde";
        });
    }
```

you can use $('#someting') with right **this**.

if you use bind to solve the problem，in the callback **this** is wrong.

Comment: What is the benefit of your solution vs. bind

Comment: The benefit is you can use **this** point to **onSomeevent** scope and use **self** point to **person** scope as your need.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which is not supported in older IEs, or jquerys [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/#jQuery-proxy-function-context)

```
function Person() {
    this.name = "abc";

    $("#something").onSomeEvent(function() {
        this.name = "cde";
    }.bind(this));
}


function Person() {
    this.name = "abc";

    $("#something").onSomeEvent($.proxy(function() {
        this.name = "cde";
    },this));
}
```